# lucene 1.3 working with java

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 1.3. I am trying to index one key and values were a list. When ever I search for the key, I should get list of results, but I am getting 0 results.i am declaring pricelistkey as Long

Here is my code which I tried.

```
String fieldName = pliBean.getProductID();
Field skuField = new Field(String.valueOf(priceListKey),fieldName, true, true, false);
doc.add(skuField);
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

This is indexed in `key:listofvalues`

The query I am passing is term query.

```
TermQuery qry = new TermQuery(new Term(key,Key));
Search(qry);
```

Comment: Lucene 1.3 is well over ten years old. Why are you using it?

Comment: well Lucene 1.3 is integrated with our framework. if we need to upgrade Lucene current version, theres' lot of depedencies included.